# ERROR: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference

Tags: ant, jenkins

I'm executing this script in jenkins using AntExec plugin. But it shows the "ERROR: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference ".

This is my script

```
<project name="MyProject" default="copy"  basedir="https://mysvn.com/Project Data/Analysis & Design/Table Structures/DB/Script.sql">
    <target name="copy">
        <copy todir="C:\Software\MyProject\Sources\myfile">
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant build files are XML - if you want to include an `&` character you have to represent it as `&amp;`.

But I'm also pretty sure that script won't do what you want it to. Try something more like this:

```
<get src="https://mysvn.com/Project%20Data/Analysis%20&amp;%20Design/Table%20Structures/DB/Script.sql"
     dest="C:\Software\MyProject\Sources\myfile" />
```

Note that I've escaped the spaces in the URL as `%20`, as required by the URI encoding rules.

Comment: can u please name one. I tried many plugins but no one helped. @Ian

Comment: @Nana Hmm, I see what you mean, you can tell Jenkins to check out a directory but not a single file.  I've edited my answer with an Ant script that should work.

Comment: Thanks bro.  But it again generates the following error.   Problem: failed to create task or type project  
Cause: The name is undefined.  
Action: Check the spelling.  
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.  
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have   taken place.

Comment: @Nana is the XML you've posted in the question the _complete_ build file?  That error suggests you've nested this XML inside another build file - `project` is supposed to be the top level element.

Comment: yes bro. I'm executing your script using the AntExec plugin in jenkins. In the script source box i enterd ur code. (only your code) fyi: in my project there is only one build step. that is executing this ant script

Comment: @Nana ok, I've looked up that plugin and it looks like the "script source" is not in fact a complete ant build script but just a fragment that could go inside a `target`.  So all you need to supply in the configuration is the `<get .../>` element.

Comment: Thanks. But again I got a security exception. Anyhow I figured out a way. What i did is checkout that directory to my workplace(happens automatically) and as a build step i executed a ant script to copy the file i wanted from there. Now it works fine. :)